# Python 3 - Temperature Converter

Tags: python-3.x

I am fairly new to any programing and I am trying to build a temperature converter function in python but I keep getting errors.
I wanted the function to first prompt the user for a temperature in Fahrenheit and convert it to Celsius;and next prompt the user for a temperature in Celsius and convert it to Fahrenheit. Below is my code. Any help will be appreciated

```
def main():
    F = input("Input the temperature in Fahrenheit: ")
    C = (5 / 9) * (float(F - 32))
    print(int(C))

    input("input the temperature in Celsius")
    F = 9/5 * (float(C + 32))
    Print(int(F))

main()
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mabook/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mabook/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 4, in main
    C = (5 / 9) * (float(F - 32))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: `print` should not be capitalized (last line of the function)

Comment: Include the full text of the errors you're getting in the body of your question.

Comment: F is a `string`. You need to do `C = (5 / 9) * (float(F) - 32)`.

Comment: Your second user input isn't getting stored anywhere.

Comment: This is the error message I get:                                                             
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mabook/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mabook/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 4, in main
    C = (5 / 9) * (float(F - 32))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Check the comment by @Miraj50 `float` is applied to `F`, you now are trying to substract an int form a string and then converting the result to float.
You may directly convert it at the time of getting the input `F = float(input("Input the temperature in Fahrenheit: "))`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error as stated in the comments is that you can't take a string from an integer. So you need to convert you input to some type that you can take away from an integer like a float but you must do this before doing the calculation.

There are other things that need to be changed to make this code work:

- `print` should be lower case
- The second input needs to be stored in a variable so we can then use it
- The brackets need to be changed when converting to Fahrenheit to make the formula correct
- Unless you have some need to truncate the number back to an int and get rid of everything after the decimal point we may as well just print the result as is. If you do need the result as an int you should consider rounding to the nearest integer and not just truncating the value

With all these changes the code could look something like this:

```
def main():
    F = input("Input the temperature in Fahrenheit: ")
    C = (5 / 9) * (float(F) - 32)
    print(C)

    C = input("input the temperature in Celsius: ")
    F = (9 / 5) * float(C) + 32
    print(F)

main()
```